# How to add a List<string> to other strings that filters results in ASP.NET MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have been stuck on this for over a day now and it's driving me nuts. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing. Anyways, I have a Users List page that is using ASP Identity framework. I have some filters at the top of the page that will filter the users by: UserName(txtbox), CompanyName(dropdown), and by Role(dropdown). My current code is filtering it, but it won't filter it with the other criteria's if they use multiple filters (like CompanyName and Role). I had to query a List string to populate my model to display in the view. So my problem I'm having trouble figuring out is how to add the "Roles" (which is the List string) to my controller code that incorporates 3 strings from the filters together. But since Roles is already a string, if I put .ToString() after it, the filter will not show any records when triggered. If I take the .ToString() off of Roles, it works only if I were to filter the Roles by itself, but it will not work with the other filters. Any suggestions on what I can do would be greatly appreciated. Here is my model:

```
public class UserList
{
    public UserList() { }

    public ApplicationUser User { set; get; }
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ListUsers", "Administrator", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="form-inline title">
        <h4>Users</h4>
        <button class="create-btn"><span class="fa-solid fa-plus"></span>&nbsp;@Html.ActionLink("Create New User", "Register", "Account", new { @class = "CreateLink" })</button>
    </div>
    <p class="filter-section">
        <label class="filter-lbl1">By Company:</label><label class="filter-ddl">@Html.DropDownList("strComp", Extensions.GetCompanyList(), "All", new { @class = "comp-ctl" })</label>
        <label class="filter-lbl2">By Role:</label><label class="filter-ddl">@Html.DropDownList("strRole", Extensions.GetRolesList(), "All", new { @class = "role-ctn" })</label><br />
        <label class="filter-lbl3">By User Name:</label><label class="filter-txtbox">@Html.TextBox("strName", "", new { @class = "name-ctl" })</label>
        <button type="button" class="red" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ListUsers", new { })'"><i class="fa solid fa-trash-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Reset</button>
        <button type="submit" class="filter-btn"><i class="fa solid fa-filter"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Filter</button>
    </p>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th>
            Company
        </th>
        <th>
            Role
        </th>
        <th>
            Last Login
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        var appUser = user.User;
        var roles = user.Roles;
        <tr>
            <td class="email">
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelitem => user.User.Id)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => user.User.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => user.User.CompanyName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => user.Roles, string.Join(",", roles))
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditUser", new { id = appUser.Id }, new { @class = "edit-link" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteUser", new { id = appUser.Id }, new { @class = "delete-link" })
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>

<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div></div>
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0: Model.PageNumber)/@Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ListUsers", new { page, strComp = ViewData["strFilter1"], strRole = ViewData["strFilter2"], strName = ViewData["strFilter3"] }))
```

And here is my code for my controller part:

```
public ActionResult ListUsers(string strFilter1, string strFilter2, string strFilter3, string strComp, string strName, string strRole, int? page)
    {
        if (strComp != null && strRole != null && strName != null)
        {
            strFilter1 = strComp;
            strFilter2 = strRole;
            strFilter3 = strName;
        }
        ViewBag.strFilter1 = strComp;
        ViewBag.strFilter2 = strRole;
        ViewBag.strFilter3 = strName;

        var user = (from u in context.Users
                    let query = from ur in context.Set<IdentityUserRole>()
                                where ur.UserId.Equals(u.Id)
                                join r in context.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                                select r.Name
                    select new UserList() { User = u, Roles = query.ToList<string>() })
        .ToList();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strComp))
        {
            //Filter results based on company selected.
            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            var pageSize = 25;
            if (strRole == null && strName == null)
            {
                var comp = user.Where(u => u.User.CompanyName.ToString().Contains(strComp));
                return View(comp.OrderBy(u => u.User.Id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
            }
            else
            {
                var compuser = user.Where(u => u.User.CompanyName.ToString().Contains(strComp) &&
                                                   u.Roles.ToString().Contains(strRole) &&
                                                   u.User.UserName.ToString().Contains(strName));
                return View(compuser.OrderBy(u => u.User.Id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
            }
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strRole))
        {
            //Filter results based on role selected.
            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            var pageSize = 25;
            if (strComp == null && strName == null)
            {
                var roll = user.Where(u => u.Roles.Contains(strRole));
                return View(roll.OrderBy(u => u.User.Id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
            }
            else
            {
                var rolluser = user.Where(u => u.Roles.Contains(strRole) &&
                                                  u.User.CompanyName.ToString().Contains(strComp) &&
                                                  u.User.UserName.ToString().Contains(strName));
                return View(rolluser.OrderBy(u => u.User.Id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
            }
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strName))
        {
            //Filter results based on the username typed in.
            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            var pageSize = 25;
            if (strComp == null && strRole == null)
            {
                var uname = user.Where(u => u.User.UserName.ToString().Contains(strName));
                return View(uname.OrderBy(u => u.User.Id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
            }
            else
            {
                var nameuser = user.Where(u => u.User.UserName.ToString().Contains(strName) &&
                                                 u.User.CompanyName.ToString().Contains(strComp) &&
                                                 u.Roles.ToString().Contains(strRole));
                return View(nameuser.OrderBy(u => u.User.Id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
            }
        }
        //var userList = user.OrderBy(u => u.User.Id).ToList();
        {
            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            var pageSize = 25;
            var userList = user.OrderBy(u => u.User.CompanyName).ToList();
            return View(userList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
    }
```

The controller is where I believe the issue is. If I leave the .ToString() off of the Roles, its works perfect if I am just filtering by the role. But if I try to filter with anything else, it filters it to empty results. I'm thinking since the Roles is a list string, for some reason it's not able to properly add to the other strings. What's weird is with my current code, it will filter records by UserName and by Role at the same time, but the CompanyName and Role do not work in sync with each other.

Comment: Does your Role list have a delimiter like `,` where you can use `var roleArr = strRole.Split(",");`?

Comment: No I don't think it does, it's just set at what my code is above. I'm pretty new to this stuff so I'm still learning the in's and outs, but how would the strRole.Split work?

Comment: The string `Split()` method allows you to pass a delimiter and it will split the string into an array. If you have `string fruit = "Apple, Orange, Banana"` if you do the following  `var fruitArr = fruit.Split(",") ` then you can access each item `fruitArr[0] = "Apple"; fruitArr[1] = "Orange"; fruitArr[2] = "Banana";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the bit of logic you want is `Enumerable.Any`.

e.g. your `Where` clause for roles can be:

`u.Roles.Any(role => role.Contains(strRole)))`

this will return true if any of the `u.Roles` contain the specified `strRole` string.

---

Edit: Sidenote, if I've read this correctly, all of your code after the `user` declaration can be simplified to just:

```cs
public ActionResult ListUsers(/*...*/)
{

    var user = /*...*/;

    var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    var pageSize = 25;

    IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> filteredUsers = user;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strComp)) {
        filteredUsers = filteredUsers.Where(u => u.User.CompanyName.ToString().Contains(strComp));
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strName)) {
        filteredUsers = filteredUsers.Where(u => u.User.UserName.ToString().Contains(strName));
    }
        
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strRole)) {
        filteredUsers = filteredUsers.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(role => role.Contains(strRole)));
    }


    return View(filteredUsers.OrderBy(u => u.User.Id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

Comment: This could potentially lead to duplicate Users being added to the `IEnumerable`. I also believe that the OP is trying to build the SQL query to use the Role list to return Users in that Role. In SQL it would be something like `where RoleName in ('strRole[0]', 'strRole[1]', ...)` In Linq it would be something like `u.Roles.Any(role => role.Name == strRole[0] || role.Name == strRole[1] ...)`

Comment: "This could potentially lead to duplicate Users being added to the IEnumerable."

That is not true. Subsequent `Where` clauses are effectively AND-ed together. (more acccurately, each is operating on the results output by the previous)

Comment: @JohnPaulR, thank you very much for your answer on trying the: u.Roles.Any(role => role.Contains(strRole))). Once I tried that, it all worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I was stuck on this for days, so it feels amazing to have figured that out. Thank you!